# Prefill pdf form in DocuSign API

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am new to Docusign API. I would like to be able to create an envelope with a pdf that has form fields filled in like customer name, adress, ... This data should not be editable in docusign. So I see many options:

1. Use templates and send TextTab data along with the
   EnvelopeDescription when creating a new envelope. But there are
   plenty of possible pdfs all with similar fields but different
   content so this is not an option for me.
2. Prefill the pdf using some third party API like PdfTron and send
   a filled one to DocuSign. But I would have to learn new API and those often cost a lot.
3. Use TransformPdfFields on the Document so that the fields are transformed into TextTabs and can be edited by an Editor recipient before sending the evelope to the signer. But in this case the filled data is only available after the Editor fills it in. And also I would like to reduce user interactions with the Docusign.
4. Send form data to DocuSign? Is it possible? I noticed PdfFieldsData property on the Document object. But it is a string and there is no description in the documentation about the format to use. Any ideas?

Clearly I prefer the 4th solution. Do you have any information how to achieve that?

Comment: Facing the same thing! Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Not really. We ended up generating pdfs from scratch as we needed more flexibility.

Comment: :-/ It seems so close to being able to work with the API, strange that it doesn't seem to be as extensible as you'd think. Thanks for the quick response!